# use regex to match a string with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I created a regex with the string I am searching for by:

```
var re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
```

And i have an array that I want to search through that has these terms:

```
var websiteName = [
  "google", "youtube", "twitter", "medium", "amazon", "airbnb", "campaiyn", "uber", "dropbox", "asana",
  "slack", "soundcloud", "reddit", "uscitp", "facebook"
];
```

If my search term is `reddit testtest test`, I would not get a match when I call the match function:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < websiteName.length; i = i + 1) {
    if(websiteName[i].match(re) != null) {
      possibleNameSearchResults[i] = i;
    }
  }
```

How can i structure my regex statement so that when I search through my array that it will still return true if just one of the words match?

Comment: Why not iterate through the websiteName array and use each element as the regexp search term for the string.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```js
var searchTerm = 'reddit testtest test';

var websiteNames = ["google", "youtube", "twitter", "medium", "amazon", "airbnb", "campaiyn", "uber", "dropbox", "asana", "slack", "soundcloud", "reddit", "uscitp", "facebook"];

// filter the websiteNames array based on each website's name
var possibleNameSearchResults = websiteNames.filter(function(website) {

  // split the searchTerm into individual words, and
  // and test if any of the words match the current website's name
  return searchTerm.split(' ').some(function(term) {
    return website.match(new RegExp(term, 'ig')) !== null;
  });
});

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(possibleNameSearchResults))
```

**Edit:** If you want the index instead of the actual value of the item, you are probably better off going with a more standard `forEach` loop, like this:

```js
var searchTerm = 'reddit testtest test',
    websiteNames = ["google", "youtube", "twitter", "medium", "amazon", "airbnb", "campaiyn", "uber", "dropbox", "asana", "slack", "soundcloud", "reddit", "uscitp", "facebook"],
    possibleNameSearchResults = []

// loop over each website name and test it against all of
// the keywords in the searchTerm
websiteNames.forEach(function(website, index) {
  var isMatch = searchTerm.split(' ').some(function(term) {
    return website.match(new RegExp(term, 'ig')) !== null;
  });
  
  if (isMatch) {
    possibleNameSearchResults.push(index);
  }
})

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(possibleNameSearchResults))
```

Comment: thank you!. is there anywa to return the index of the search result instead of the actual value?

Comment: @ogk - Sure, I've edited my answer to show another example that provides the index instead of the value.